# Eclipse WebLogic debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I know you can debug by just clicking the debug icon in Eclipse.  Is it possible to start WebLogic from the command line with debugging and still debug? When I do that, in Eclipse under server I see that the status is "Started", not "Debugging".  Can this only be done by setting up remote debugging?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add parameters to the JAVA_OPTIONS in the startWebLogic.cmd (or startWebLogic.sh):

> -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=1044,suspend=n -Xdebug

Then, in Eclipse you have to use remote debugging indeed. 
Add a new Remote Java Application in the Debug Configurations  (via the menu: Run - Debug Configurations).
Make sure the correct project is selected (Browse button) and fill in *localhost* in Host and *1044* in Port. The other options you can leave unchanged.

If you click debug you should be able to see your remote WebLogic running in the Debug perspective.

If you see a WebLogic started under Servers, you are looking at an embedded server and not at the one you started via the command line. Make sure to stop any embedded server before starting via the command line as they will not be able to run on the same port together anyway.