# how to debug java web application in eclips with weblogic server

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I have java application with Eclipse IDE and WebLogic 11g server. Is it possible to debug application remotely? if yes how?

Answer (score 12):

In `startWeblogic.cmd`file, add the following line before `ENDLOCAL` line.

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n
```

The Weblogic Server console should display the message:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
```

In eclipse follow the instructions below:

1. Select **Run > Debug
   Configurations...** from the workbench menu bar (or **Debug
   Configurations...** from the drop-down menu on the Debug tool bar
   button) to show the launch configuration dialog.
2. Select the **Remote Java Application** in the list of configuration
   types on the left.
3. Click the **New** toolbar button. A new remote launch configuration
   is created and three tabs are shown: Connect, Source, and Common.
4. In the **Project** field of the **Connect** tab, type or browse to select
   the project to use as a reference for the launch (for source
   lookup). A project does not need to be specified.
5. The **Connection Type** field of the **Connect** tab allows you to choose
   how you will connect to the virtual machine. In most cases, you will
   be attaching to the vm at a specific location, in which case select
   Standard (Socket Attach). the rest of these instructions assume you
   have chosen this option. The Standard (Socket Listen) connection
   type creates a launch that will listen for incoming connections from
   a remote VM. You will need to specify a port that the launch will
   listen at.
6. In the **Host** field of the Connect tab, type the IP address or domain
   name of the host where the Java program is running.If the program is running on the same machine as the workbench, type localhost.
7. In the **Port** field of the Connect tab, type the port where the
   remote VM is accepting onnections. Generally, this port is specified
   when  the remote VM is launched.
8. The **Allow termination of remote** VM flag is a toggle that determines
   whether the Terminate command is enabled in the debugger. Select
   this option if you want to be able to terminate the VM to which you
   are connecting.
9. Click **Debug**. The launch attempts to connect to a VM
       at the specified address and port, and the result is displayed in
       the Debug view. If the launcher is unable to connect to a VM at the
       specified address, an error message appears.

Docs:

- [Using Remote Debugging - BEA WebLogic Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs92/studio33/IDEUserGuide/WebLogicServer.html#DebugRemote)
- [Weblogic remote debugging using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882203/weblogic-remote-debugging-using-eclipse)
- [Debug Java applications remotely with Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/)
- [Using the remote Java application launch configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-remotejava_launch_config.htm)

Comment: "-Xnoagent Disables support for the old JDB debugger." (- internet) So in newer versions of Java this is unneeded.

Comment: "If you see a WebLogic started under Servers, you are looking at an embedded server and not at the one you started via the command line. Make sure to stop any embedded server before starting via the command line as they will not be able to run on the same port together anyway." - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19806670/1599699

Comment: Lastly... make sure you set MW_HOME as well, if you're seeing "Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.Server".

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you enable remote debugging on your startup script for Weblogic:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n
```

(address is the port number; remember this number)

Second, you need to set up a new Remote Web Application debug configuration in Eclipse:

```
Run -> Debug Configurations...
```

then create a new Remote Web Application configuration. Make sure you specify your host and port (noted above), and add any source for the web app on the Source tab.

You should now be able to run that debug configuration to debug a web app in Eclipse on the specified Weblogic server.