# eclipse debug war deployed in weblogic

Tags: java, debugging, jakarta-ee, weblogic, web-deployment

I have an application ear that is deployed into weblogic. Is there any way to debug an ear deployment?

Hoping ear deployment cant be debugged . I extracted the war from ear. Turned to war to physical folder by renaming the war extention to zip and then unzipping it.
Then pointed this physical location as deployment in weblogic. But then too its not working.

Any possible solution to debug an application deployed as ear using eclipse?
pls note weblogic is integrated into eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The below link gives clear steps in setting up the remote debugging in your Eclipse/Weblogic setup:

[how to debug java web application in eclips with weblogic server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104666/how-to-debug-java-web-application-in-eclips-with-weblogic-server)