# Eclipse with Weblogic 12c is not stopping in breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, debugging, weblogic

I hope you could help me. I'm newbie in Weblogic and debugging in Eclipse. I've followed different threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104666/how-to-debug-java-web-application-in-eclips-with-weblogic-server), but I'm not able to make Eclipse stop at WS breakpoints. This is how I have it currently configured:

1.- I have raised Weblogic 12c from the command line (the NodeManager is also raised) debugging in 8453 port: 
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww9aq.png)

2.- I've launched Remote Aplication Debug in Weblogic in 8453 port:
[Eclipse Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unMme.png)

3.- However, if I launch a Webservice request, and having breakpoints within the Webservice code, the application does not stop at those breakpoints:  [Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpuO5.png)

It seems that when I launch the request, the Remote Java application "ignores" the request, (it looks like nothing happens in debugged VM ,no new threads, nothing).

Maybe I'm listening the wrong port/VM? What could I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you setting/enabling the breakpoints before you attach to the remote application, or after?

Comment: I've enabled the breakpoints before attaching to remote application

Comment: Try it the other way.

Comment: It worked!. Thanks!